# C Programming If Statements Not Working

Tags: c, if-statement

My if statements aren't working and I am not sure why. Can someone point out my error, thank you. This is just a kinda dumb program I am making just for practice, I am setting a lot more variables along the way.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{

    //This is a program that determines what circle of hell the user will be put in.  Inspired by Dante's Divine Comedy
    char firstQuestion;

    float total = 0;

    printf("ABANDON ALL HOPE, YOU WHO ENTER HERE\n\n");
    printf("Welcome to the gate of hell. I am going to ask you a series of questions and you will answer them truthfully.\n\n\n");

    printf("I would first like to ask you, do you believe you are a good person?(Y or N)\n");
    scanf_s(" %c", &firstQuestion);
    if (firstQuestion == 'Y'){
        printf("We will see about that.\n");
        total = total + 10;
    }
    else if (firstQuestion == 'N'){
    printf("I'm not surprised.\n");
}
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `main()`  --> `int main(void)`

Comment: I am using Microsoft visual studio by the way.  That is why my scanf() is scanf_s().

Comment: You should query for `=='Y' || ... =='y'` because your inputs are case-sensitive

Comment: Also you might want to add an else-path that returns "invalid input" to the user...

Comment: For simple exercise programs you should rather use `scanf` which is not the same as `scanf_s`. See Nishant's answer below.

Comment: Seconding Michael here. While learning the language, stick to the standard functions, not the one Microsoft tells you to use... once you learned the language, *keep* sticking to the standard. ;-)

Comment: Visual Studio won't run my program with scanf, so I have to use scanf_s in order to get information from the user.  Unless you know of any other alternatives?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if VS would *refuse* `scanf()`. It gives you a *warning*, but it should compile (provided you give the correct arguments). That being said, reading user input via `scanf*()` is discouraged. Read a line of input (`fgets()`), then parse it in-memory. `scanf*()` does not give sufficient capabilities to recover from erroneous input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scanf_s() is not a drop-in replacement for scanf().  You should include a buffer size when the input parameter is a character or string.

```
scanf_s(" %c", &firstQuestion,1);  //For single character

char s[10];

scanf_s("%9s", s, 10);    //For reading a string
```